# Missing Hardware OATH Token Activities in Azure Audit Log

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, active-directory, microsoft-entra-id

### Background:

According to the Azure [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/monitoring-health/reference-audit-activities#authentication-methods), the following activity types should be visible in the Azure Audit logs:

- Assign Hardware Oath Token
- Bulk upload Hardware Oath Token
- Create Hardware Oath Token
- Delete Hardware Oath Token
- Update Hardware Oath Token

#### Issue:

I attempted to create and assign a hard OATH token to a user in the Azure Portal. This resulted only in a `User registered security info` activity (specifically, *"User registered Activate Legacy Hardware Oath Authentication Method"*). None of the expected activities listed in the documentation appeared in the audit log.

#### Question:

Can someone help me understand why the specific activities (Assign, Create, Delete, Update of Hardware Oath Token) are not showing up in the audit log? What might I be doing wrong? My goal is to query the audit log to track when a hardware Oath token is assigned, deleted, or updated.

Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated.